# How to use C++ keyword in .cpp file?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

According to my requirement.
Suppose I have below files

```
abc.h //used for C file

int new; // All C++ keywords, new use as a variable
char class; // All C++ keywords, class use as a variable
Actual_task();

abc.c //C file

main()
{
...//Body of file where they have used new and class variable
new++; //for an example
class = 'C';
actual_task();//One function is getting called here
}
```

I have a `.cpp` file which needs the file `abc.h` needs to be `included` to use `actual_task()`:

```
CPPfile.cpp

extern "C"{
#include "abc.h"
}
```

Then it throws `errors` like `class` and `new` can not used just like a variable.

Then how to use the `C` header files in `cpp` files?

Comment: Bummer... you can't.

Comment: Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: It is a separate task which is getting invoked feom a c file but now I have to control it and need to invoke it from a cpp file

Comment: Note that `extern "C"` does not mean "compile this as C code". It's still C++; only the generated names change to match what the C compiler does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use C header files that use C++ keywords for other purposes than what they are meant for in C++.

The proper solution is to change the header file so it does not use the C++ keywords any more.

If the C++ keywords are used for global variables (that are not used by the C++ code) or function parameter names, you might get away with a construct like this:

```
#define new new_
#define class class_
extern "C" {
    #include "abc.h"
}
#undef class
#undef new
```

Comment: emphasis on the /might/ since defining C++ keywords isn't really allowed

Answer (score 0):

Change the headers so that the variables / functions don't have names which are reserved words in C++.

If anyone says you can't then tell them you're being ask to merge source code from two separate programming languages which are, in this sense, incompatible. It's a known issue with a known solution.